# Can we assign names to buttons like we have in icons on a desktop?

Tags: android

I am making a TableRow of Buttons in a TableLayout, which has images on it.
I want to add names below the buttons, like we have for icons on a desktop.
Is it possible by any chance?

I am posting my code here:

```
public void populate_table() {

    TableLayout tablelayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.devtable);
    TextView text = new TextView(context);


    for (int i = 0; i < table_row; i++) {
        TableRow tablerow = new TableRow(context);

        tablerow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 50, 0));

        tablelayout.addView(tablerow);

        for (int j = 0; j < table_column; j++) {
            Button button = new Button(context);
            button.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(100,100,0 ));
            //text.setText(String.valueOf(i) +", " + String.valueOf(j));
            text.setText("Bonny");

            LinearLayout buttonlayout = new LinearLayout(context);
            buttonlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            buttonlayout.addView(button);
            buttonlayout.addView(text);

            tablerow.addView(buttonlayout);


        }
    }

}
```

The stack trace error is:

```
03-15 05:17:25.911  10043-10043/com.example.bonny.sandterm E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3407)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3278)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3223)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3199)
        at com.example.bonny.sandterm.MainActivity.populate_table(MainActivity.java:211)
        at com.example.bonny.sandterm.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:139)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4107)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17160)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @ArshidKV could you show me with an example?
any sytax would be of great help!

Comment: @Andrew Orobator This is a method "populate_table()" and this is jus a part of a big code.

Anyway, could you just post me an example to merge a button and a textview in a Linear Layout?
I can workout from there onwards! Thanks

Comment: I meant exactly what line is causing the crash.

Comment: Maybe the order that you're making the view is wrong. Try making the tablerow in its entirety before putting it into the table.

Comment: @AndrewOrobator Its probably the line where i try to add two views in a LinearLayout.
`buttonlayout.addView(button);
 buttonlayout.addView(text);`

Could you just give me an example to add two views(Button and Textview) into a LinearLayout?

Comment: @AndrewOrobator OK I have got the issue!
Declaring the Textview outside the inner loop caused it to crash!
anyway...overall your method worked! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a label like effect, what you can do is have a TextView underneath each Button in a LinearLayout. Since you're creating these buttons in code, first create a `LinearLayout buttonLayout`. Make sure to call

```
buttonLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

because the default orientation is horizontal. First add your button to buttonLayout so that it appears at the top. Then make a `TextView` and set the text you want on it before adding it to `buttonLayout`.

Comment: I guess you didnt get the question. I want the text below the button...not on it.
Button.setText() will create the text on the button, but i want the text below it, like an icon on desktop!

Comment: Ah okay, see my new answer.

Comment: Thanks, this looks more comprehensible.
But I tried to add both textview n button on the LinearLayout and it crashes.
The code i Wrote was:
`LinearLayout buttonlayout = new LinearLayout(context);
 buttonlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);                buttonlayout.addView(button);
buttonlayout.addView(text);

tablerow.addView(buttonlayout);`

Comment: Can you post your stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in xml file

```
        <Button    
            android:id="@+id/btn_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Icon Name"/>
```

Comment: Actually I am creating the Buttons dynamically from the code.
So there are no xml contents of the buttons.
I need to do it from the code.
any luck?